# How to get selected item from table on button click in object editor pimcore?

Tags: javascript, php, pimcore

I have added a button in **pimcore** panel in object editor. On button click how can I fetch selected records from the table?

Table:

[image: Table Screenshot]

So far I have tried this:

```
 postOpenObject: function (object, type) {
     object.toolbar.add({
         iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_export',
         scale: 'small',
         handler: function () {                        
             const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
             // I need to pass selected items in a function
             req.open("GET", '/admin/export-xyz/', true);
         }.bind(this, object)
     });
     pimcore.layout.refresh();
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are passing `object` in bind, you can `object.search.grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();` Then make a loop to find the selected row.

```
handler: function () {                        
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // I need to pass selected items in a function
      let selections = object.search.grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

for (let i= 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
   console.log(selections[i].id);
}
      req.open("GET", '/admin/export-xyz/', true);
 }.bind(this, object)
```